# Why I can do limit epsilon tends to zero?

Tags: real-analysis

I am confused about limit as epsilon tends to zero. For example:

Let $x$, $y$, $\epsilon$ be any positives real numbers. Then I know (from previous calculations) that $x \geq y - \epsilon$. Now, why can I say that this implies $x \geq y$?

On the other hand, if I have something like that:

Let $X$ be a normed linear space. If $Y$ is closed subspace of $X$, then for all $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists $x$ from $S_X$ so that $dist(x,Y) \gt 1-\epsilon$. ($S_X$ is a unit sphere)

I see the difference: the first example is "for all x, y, $\epsilon$" something holds and the second is "for all $\epsilon$ there exists x so that something hold".

But still I don't understand why in the first example I can do limit $\epsilon \to 0$ and in the second I can't.

Thank you.

Comment: What statement exactly are you trying to conclude in the second case that you don't think you can do?

Comment: @rogerl In the second case I obtain: there exists x so that dist(x,Y) > 1. And this is false. So I can't do limit epsilon tends to zero like in the first example.

Comment: The first statement should be: for some fixed $x,y$ we know that for all $ ϵ>0$ that $x\ge y-ϵ$. Then already $x\ge y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the distinction between $\ge$ and $>$ in the limit. Suppose $x=y$. Then it is true that for all $\epsilon>0$, $x>y-\epsilon$, and yet $x=y$. Put another way, the only thing you can conclude from $x>y-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$ is that it is *not* the case that $x<y$: for if it were, simply choose $\epsilon = \frac{y-x}{2}$ to get a contradiction.

The fact that in the second case $x$ depends on $\epsilon$ simply reflects the fact that different points on the unit sphere are different distances away from $Y$. But again, as above, you can conclude that $d(x,Y)\ge 1$ (not $>$) for all $x\in S_X$.